# Not stisfying the condition if request.is_ajax(): in django view

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to Configure the URL and view to check if javascript is calling the view or not using the ajax call.
I am able to Pass this JSON data using AJAX POST method  to the django URL.
But in view its not entering in to the condition if request.is_ajax(): it directly goes to the else part in view.

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt    
def lat_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.POST.all()
            print data
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': data}), content_type="application/json")
    else :
        print "you are not in ajax"
        return render_to_response('poll/ajax_test.html', locals())
```

ajax request

```
var data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(data1)
            //alert(data1)
            alert("hi")
            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/lat_ajax/",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType:"jsonp",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success:function(response){
                                        alert ("resp: "+response.data);
                                        alert("you in ajax")
                    }

            });

            return false;

                });
```

This html page is not from the same project. I am using the django project url to pass data and then send that data to one email address without saving it. Is this a cross domain problem? In chrome i am getting the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/test.everycrave.com/contact/contact.php. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. contact.html:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/lat_ajax/?callback=jQuery18102593700629658997_13…1%40gmail.com&subject=Fwd%3A+DB+design&message=sdfsddfsfds&_=1399357203734". jquery.js:3
send jquery.js:3
p.extend.ajax jquery.js:3
(anonymous function) contact.html:256
p.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
g.handle.h
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an issue with cross domain requests. Normally the server has to tell you which HTTP headers it accepts when you are doing CORS. In order to use `.is_ajax()` the request has to contain

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

header (that's exactly what `.is_ajax()` checks). But by default the HTTP standard forbids to send that header via CORS. So to make it work your server not only has to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header but also

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
```

Then you have to set that header in your request manually:

```
$.ajax({
    // some settings
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

**EDIT** I've just realized that you are actually doing JSONP, which is not CORS. In that case there is no way to set that header since JSONP **is not** AJAX at all. It is only wrapped to look like AJAX, but what actually happens under the hood is that the browser creates a `<script>` tag that points to the URL. It is impossible to change that. I advice switching to CORS. Other possibility is to send additional info in URL (as a query string). Not elegant but it will work.

Comment: getting this error 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll/lat_ajax/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.'

Comment: @Sharad CORS is not an easy concept. Read this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ Also the error is correct: the only way to do what you want is either to move the resource to the same origin or use CORS.

Comment: ok,  Its entering to the view but not satisfying the ajax condition. When i removed ajax condition then also its not satisfying the if request.method == 'POST': condition also. Its going to the else part.

Comment: @Sharad You are not listening. JSONP **is not** AJAX. It is **always GET** no matter what `type` you use and you **cannot add custom headers**. Read more about JSONP here: http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONP.php